# how to check context menu event is triggered from mouse or keyboard in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find the source of context menu event in jquery , is this event is triggred from mouse or context menu key?

In contextmenu event arguments i cant get any key related information, how to i get this details from event arguments?

Comment: You have some code to go with this?

Comment: yes, I have bound context menu event for container element. If contextmenu triggers by mouse, i can get exact target element and position inside the container. But by key i cant do this.

Comment: You have some code to go with this (that needs posting in the question)?

Comment: I want to prevent the default context menu action only by key, but i need contextmenu action by mouse.

Answer (score 0):

The [`contextmenu`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu) event has a `button` property which should return which mouse button was used to fire the event.

So, `window.oncontextmenu = function(e){if(e.button!==2) e.preventDefault();}` should be enough.

However, there seems to be a bug on mac os, where if you call contextmenu with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ click, `event.button`is set to `2` but `event.buttons` is set to `1`, so you may want to also try `window.oncontextmenu = function(e){if(e.buttons!==2) e.preventDefault();}`

Comment: Please note that I wasn't able to test it on a win keyboard though so let me know if it does work.